# Recycler view makes a gap between items when an item is removed

Tags: android

I am using a recycler view to show some cardviews as a list. When I removed a particular card from the position. It goes invisible but a gap forms in the space where the card was occupied. How can pull the below card view items to that position(using any animations etc?,)
The removal code is given below.

In adapter class,

```
holder.ivClose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        holder.llRating.startAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,R.anim.popup_exit));
        holder.llRating.setVisibility(GONE);
        mListner.onCardRemoved(position);
    }
});
```

And in Fragment class code is

```
@Override
public void onCardRemoved(int position) {
    courseCards.remove(position);
    adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: please paste your whole code of view holder class

Comment: It is more complicated. I am using a heterogeneous recycler view. So it will take time for you to understand. If you can answer this question by a simple example, it is also fine for me.

Comment: You should not set visibility to holder. It just holds your view, and after you removed it you want to reuse it. Use only mListener.onCardRemoved()

Comment: It is not getting resolved.!